# Loading animation stucked/freezed when webview loads

Tags: ios, swift, animation, wkwebview

I load the progress loading animation and when the response from Alamofire comes I use part of the response to construct the full url I need to load in the wkwebview and then I trigger webview.load(..).

My problem is that the progress loading animation gets stuck as soon as webview.load(..) starts to happen and remain stuck till I hide() it.

How can I actually have my animation to keep moving meanwhile the webview starts loading the page?

**MyViewController.swift**

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler {

    var webView: WKWebView?

    @IBOutlet weak var webViewContainer: UIView!

    var webConfig:WKWebViewConfiguration {
        get {
            let webCfg:WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

            let userController:WKUserContentController = WKUserContentController()
            userController.add(self, name: "mycontroller")

            webCfg.userContentController = userController;

            return webCfg;
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView = WKWebView (frame: webViewContainer.bounds, configuration: webConfig)
        webView!.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        webView?.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        webViewContainer.addSubview(webView!)

        loadWebview()
    }

    func loadWebview(){
        Loading.shared.show(self.view)

        Alamofire.request(MYAPI, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .responseJSON { response in
                let url = URL(string: "https://path-to-load/\(response.key)")
                    self.webView!.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
        }

    }

    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        let message = message.body as! [String:AnyObject]
        let event = message["event"] as? String ?? "empty"

        switch (event){
        case "loading-finished":
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                Loading.shared.hide(animated: true)
            }
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }


}
```

**Loading.swift**

```
public class Loading {
        var blurredEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "loading_image"))

        class var shared: Loading {
            struct LoadingStatic {
                static let instance: Loading = Loading()
            }
            return LoadingStatic.instance
        }

        init() {
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
            blurredEffectView.contentView.addSubview(imageView)
        }

        public func show(_ view: UIView, inView: Bool = false) {
            var window: UIView!
            if inView == false, let w = view.window {
                window = w
            } else {
                window = view
            }

            if blurredEffectView.superview == window {
                return
            }

            let rotation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
            rotation.toValue = NSNumber(value: Double.pi * 2)
            rotation.duration = 1
            rotation.isCumulative = true
            rotation.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
            imageView.layer.add(rotation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")

            imageView.center = window.center
            blurredEffectView.frame = window.bounds
            window.addSubview(blurredEffectView)

            blurredEffectView.fadeIn()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try put `webView.load` inside `DispatchQueue.main.async` ?

Comment: Yes but the loading still freezes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possible solutions:

**1) Make the loading happens in Application Window when you want a full screen Loading (inview == false by default) and keep loadWebview() in viewDidLoad**

```
public func show(_ view: UIView? = nil, inView: Bool = false) {
        var window: UIView!
        if inView == false, let w = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window {
            window = w
        } else {
            window = view
        }
     ...
```

**2) Move loadWebview() from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear**

The important part that is moving here is `Loading.shared.show(self.view)`. I wasn't able to animate the components of my view until it has finished laying out (which happens exactly in viewDidAppear()).

*More details:* *`viewDidLoad` is called after the MyViewController has been initialised and has initialised the main view but before the view is presented to the UI. This means that viewDidLoad allows me to setup the ViewController and the View, before it is shown to the user for interactions.*

Although it was a nice and quick solution, in some situation this may not work as expected as **viewDidAppear can be called twice,** and hence showing the loading view twice which will result in a weird ux.